# How are you dealing with Redux store typescript types and initial value without class

Tags: typescript

Since we can't use classes in react/redux I wonder if there is a better option than use of type/interface.
Most of us have kind of domain object

```
interface CounterState {
  value: number;
}
```

and then in createSlice we are setting

```
initialState = {
  value: 0
} as CounterState;
```

It looks ok for small example. But for longer types you move type declaration to separate file and then developers tend to keep initialisation as duplication of state.

If I would use classes it looks much better and combine property type and default value declaration.

```
class CounterState {
  value: 0;
}

initialState = new CounterState();
```

I know I can create factory function `newCounterState()` which will return default instance of interface but it looks like that is why we have classes.

Does anyone have a better idea how to model your state/domain?

Answer (score 2):

I find people often over-declare types in typescript instead of letting the compiler tell you if there's an error.

In the below example, I haven't specifically given `initialState` a type, but it will work just fine when given to the reducer because it satisfies `CounterState`. If you add a new property to `CounterState` and forget to update `initialState`, the typescript compiler will yell at you.

Ultimately, I personally encourage people to use less type declarations and let the compiler do their work for them. I know that's not everybody's cup of tea, some people prefer to be explicit, but I personally haven't found that helpful in practice (ymmv)

So here's what I'd do, declare a type, and then use a plain object.

```
type CounterState = {
   value: number;
}

const initialState = {
   value: 0;
}
```

FWIW, `types` and `interfaces` are largely (not 100%, but largely) interchangeable. I prefer `types` because I prefer to create union types over using `extends` - `extends` feels to OOP to me when most of my code is functional.

> If I would use classes it looks much better and combine property type and default value declaration.

Redux and react and front-end in general leans very very strongly on immutability. I think you just need to get used to dealing with plain objects/plain arrays and declaring your types for these separately.

Comment: I like more functional approach than to much oop. My argument to use more specific types is to build real domain in redux and use react to render it. I’m missing kind of immutable DataClass or record type in TS so I could declare nice type with defaults without any functions. The closest I see right now is class  with no functions.

Comment: @bizon a class with no functions is a “plain object”, that I wrote in my answer, whose type I defined. Record types do exist, but I don’t think they’ll be of much use to you here because they’re too generic, their keys are arbitrary string values - you want specific types - objects that have specific keys